HTML table row not resizing on mobile
I'm having a table with multiple rows and columns on Svelte. It can resize fine on desktop using the devtool, but when I try it on my phone and tablet the rows get very tall.
this is the code for the table
<table id="seat-table">
    <tbody>
        {#each ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] as rowLetter}
            <tr>
                {#each [1, 2, 3] as rowSeat}
                    <!-- content here -->
                    <Seat bind:seats seatPosition={`${rowLetter}${rowSeat}`} />
                {/each}

                <div class="block"></div>

                {#each [4, 5, 6] as rowSeat}
                    <!-- content here -->

                    <Seat bind:seats seatPosition={`${rowLetter}${rowSeat}`} />
                {/each}

                <div class="block"></div>

                {#each [7, 8, 9] as rowSeat}
                    <!-- content here -->

                    <Seat bind:seats seatPosition={`${rowLetter}${rowSeat}`} />
                {/each}
            </tr>
        {/each}
    </tbody>
</table>

<style lang="scss">
    #seat-table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .block {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>

And this is for the individual seat
<td>
    <button class="seat" on:click={() => addOrRemove(seatPosition)}>
        {#if seats.includes(seatPosition)}
            <img src="/icons/selectedCheck.svg" alt="Seat {seatPosition} Selected" />
        {:else}
            <img src="/icons/seatIcon.png" alt="Seat {seatPosition}" />
        {/if}
    </button>
</td>

<style lang="scss">
    .seat {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;

        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
        border-radius: 0.3rem;
        cursor: pointer;

        img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        &:hover {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }
    }

    button {
        all: unset;
    }
</style>

This resizes fine

iPhone 7

iPad Air 5

The site is live on https://seatbox.vercel.app and the full code is on https://github.com/PatatoBit/seatbox

Please create a minimal reproduction and include the entire code in the question. Questions have to be self-contained; links should only be supplementary, never necessary.

Ok! Will do that.

@brunnerh I've made an edit to the code. Thanks for letting me know!

Did you check that all the CSS features are supported on the devices?

I just checked. Seemed to all be supported. They’re mostly basic properties but I’m not sure if tables behave differently and I haven’t tried on android.

Your "block"'s to separate groups is highly irregular.  Table rows (TR elements) can only have TD elements as children.  You're basically using a table to lay out content, which is a practice that plagued the Internet 20 years ago and now is completely forgotten.  You should switch to a grid or flex container to avoid this kind of errors.

alrighty thanks! do you mind posting this comment as an answer?
